# SnackBar is not displaying in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Hi I want to display the `SnackBar` on performing certain action but it is not displaying. I am running app on ios. I see the logs also, there is no error.

Does anyone know what could be the reason ?

```
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    authHandler
        .sendPasswordResetEmail(
            emailController.text)
        .then((void nothing) {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
          content: Text(
              'Password has been reset successfully. Please check your email.'));

      Scaffold
          .of(context)
          .showSnackBar(snackBar);
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        Navigator.pop(context);
      });
    }).catchError((e) => print(e));
  }
```

Comment: Is it shown if you comment out `Navigator.pop(context);`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes what is the solution of it ?

Comment: It's probably removed by the `pop(...)` command

Comment: Yes Any other way to show it ? I have to pop the screen too

Comment: Try it the other way around. First pop, then `showSnackBar()`

Comment: Not working that way also

Comment: Did you move out `Navigator.pop(context)` from `setState(() { ... })`? This would change the order again because `setState(...)` might be executed delayed.

Comment: It is like `setState(() {
                                    isLoading = false;
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                    final snackBar = SnackBar(
                                        content: Text(
                                            'Password has been reset successfully. Please check your email.'));

                                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                                  });`

Comment: Yeah, move `Navigator.pop(context)` out of `setState(() {...})`. There is no need to have it there.

Comment: Not working. same as earlier

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Would need to investigate, but don't have the time.